# How to search a data from one range to another range in Realm database

Tags: android, sorting, listview, range, realm

I am working in a Realm database. I am saving some data in the database. Say `name,age,address,phone number`.

I am using list view to view the data in the UI.
My question is if I am saving names which are not in order(not in alphabetical order) then how to sort them in order.

And one more question is after sorting the names I wanna view only few names in the list view(say if i type range as from C to H) C=represents the names starting with C likewise H.
Can anyone please help me in this.

Comment: Have you ever checked [https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/) ?

Answer (score 2):

To get data in sorted order, use like this

```
RealmResults<DataModel>resultsd =
                realm.where(DataModel.class)
                        .findAllSorted("name");
```

For second questions, use like this

```
 RealmResults<DataModel>resultsd =
                realm.where(DataModel.class)
                      .contains("name","c").or().contains("name","h").findAll();
```

Comment: does `or` not require a group?

Comment: I am using date as a string so it will show only the date which i type. So i want the solution if i use date in that edit boxes. I wanna get the dates from range to range whatever i type in the edit box

Answer (score 1):

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#lessThan-java.lang.String-java.util.Date-

You use: lessThan and greaterThan or between()

```
final RealmResults<Dog> puppies = realm.where(Dog.class).greaterThan("age", 2).lessThan("age", 10).findAll();
```

As far as I know ,this also works with Strings, so if greaterThan("name", "C") it will have names with C.

And for sorting, you can use Collections.sort() on the arraylist before adding to Realm, but sorting and then adding to the DB will have no effect. Cause the data that you get when querying for RealmResults, is based on the query you make.

For the query to sort, you can to:

```
RealmResults<Dog>results = realm.where(Dog.class).findAllSorted("name");
```

Comment: i wanna use it in a search view. can i use two search view for this data which i have posted. if so please let me know the way how to do that

Comment: You can make 2 edit texts, and use them as the input for the range. And it will query results, only if both edit texts are completed.
And after that try:

    realm.where(Dog.class).greaterThan("name", editText1.getText().toString()).lessThan("name", editText2.getText().toString()).findAll();

Comment: Its easy to use it in search view but for two edit boxes its difficult for me . Can anyone put an example for the two text box search to view the range of data in list view  as discussed above. please

Comment: You are kidding right?
My comment before this has an example... :) I wrote it from my head, and it was not tested. But it should work.
http://pastebin.com/a9LFvpHt

Comment: But 1 problem i  am having. That greater than and lesser than is not working. Only ".contains" is working. Even if i use ".contains" only that data which i am typing in edit text is showing but not the data between the edit text boxes data. How to resolve that

Comment: What I suggest, add also a int inside your users. just for test.
then try this:

     `RealmResults<Person> teens = realm.where(Person.class).between("age", 13, 20).findAll();`

THEN change to:

     `RealmResults<Person> teens = realm.where(Person.class).between("name", "A", "C").findAll();`

See what happens, if it works with ints, and it doesn't work with Strings

Comment: Sorry mate, I don't have any other ideeas. Fetch the whole db and filter it yourself?
Email info@realm.io and ask them, they are pretty open to questions and friendly, so they should fill you in on this. Just post a answer cause I'm curious too

Comment: If you can change the model of the "Person", Create a new int like letterInt. Translate the first letter of each name into a int. Something like A = 0, B = 1 , etc. and then, do the call how I did it with between, but using the "letterInt" variable, instead of name. and the values from the editText you also transform by that logic  :-?